# Anyone know much about lua tables,classes, and functions?

Tags: arrays, function, class, lua, lua-table

I was just wondering why this returned Mexico not England? I've been trying to separate x1 to x6 by their properties, like continent, but I haven't made much progress.

```
world = {continent = "", country = ""}


function world:new (o,continent,country)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.continent= continent or ""
   self.country = country or "";
   return o
end


x1 = world:new(nil,"Europe","England")
x2 = world:new(nil,"Europe","France")
x3 = world:new(nil,"Africa","Algeria")
x4 = world:new(nil,"Africa","Nigera")
x5 = world:new(nil,"America","United States")
x6 = world:new(nil,"America","Mexico")

list_1 = {x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6}

print(list_1[1].country)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of `new`, `self` is the metatable, and o is the object. Setting attributes on `self` overwrites the previous values. So, change

```
self.continent= continent or ""
self.country = country or ""
```

to

```
o.continent= continent or ""
o.country = country or ""
```